# Embedded Code Snippet / Text Box in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word

https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/object-oriented-programming

If you visit the above website and copy the the code (as in highlight the text and select copy and not use the embedded button)

When you paste the code back in MS Word it copies over the same black box which keeps resizing as per the length of code in it. It is not a text box (as in you cant select it/format it).

Code Snippet in MS Word Screenshot:

[image: Code Snippet in MS Word Screenshot]

Can you please tell how can we add this in from within MS Word and recolor it?

It is much easier to work around with as it is not a text box and does not get selected when you click on the text

Comment: hi Harry. So I am copying the text by highlighting it and (right click copy).

Comment: Then I am pasting it back in MS Word (with option keep source formatting). This pastes it as text within the black  box which keeps resizing as you add more text in it or delete the text. But it is not like the text box we add within MS Word usually. You cant select and resize the text box using mouse-clicks

Comment: [How do you display code snippets in MS Word preserving format and syntax highlighting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387453/how-do-you-display-code-snippets-in-ms-word-preserving-format-and-syntax-highlig)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When copying text into Word with keep source formatting, you get text
with the same font and fill-color as in the source.

This is not a text-box, it's only lines that have black as background-color.

To get rid of the colors, either:

- Paste without keep source formatting
- Select the text and in the Home pane click the Clear All Formatting
  icon [image]

You may create such effects by combining on the Home pane
font and highlight colors with colors from the Design pane
Page Borders icon.